# Optimization question related to calculus.

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose we have arbitrary real numbers $a,b$.

We want to maximize $a^2 + b^2$ subject to $a + b = c$, for some constant $c$.

How would one do this?

Comment: You can get as big as you like

Comment: The function you are maximizing is equivalent to the square of distance from the origin.  What point on a straight line has the greatest distance (which you would then square) from the origin?

Comment: This problem would be more interesting if a^2+b^2 = c and you were maximizing a+b (still not difficult, but more interesting).

Answer (score 1):

Let's change the notation a bit, to make things more familiar: we'll use $x$ and $y$ instead of $a$ and $b$.

So, we're interested in the value of $x^2+ y^2$. But this is just the square of the distance from the point $(x,y)$ to the origin. We're asked "how large can this get"? The only constraint is that $x + y = c$, which says that $(x,y)$ lies on some line. By traveling along this line, we can make the (squared) distance $x^2+y^2$ as large as we like. So, there is no maximum, or the maximum is "infinity".

Are you sure you're supposed to maximizing, not minimizing?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

From the constraint, $b = c-a$ so you are maximizing
$$
a^2+b^2 = a^2 + (c-a)^2 = f(a)
$$
with $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Can you finish this?

Comment: $b=c-a$ not $a-c$

Comment: @almagest sorry fixed

Answer (score 0):

Say $u=a^2+b^2$ and we consider that $a$ is the independent variable and $b$ depends on $a$ via the constraint $b=c-a$.

Hence, $u=a^2+(c-a)^2=2a^2-2ca+c^2$

Now, by the problem, $\frac{du}{da}=0$

so we have that $$4a-2c=0 \Rightarrow a=\frac{c}{2}$$

and $$b=\frac{c}{2}$$

Also, $\frac{d^2u}{da^2}=4>0$

So this is the minimum value of $u$ and is equal to $u=\frac{c^2}{2}$.

Hence there is no extreme value as maxima. And the absolute maxima is infinity.